# How to add a java script handler for button click event in odoo 10?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-9

I want to make a handler for button in header using java script.  My view model is given below :

```
     <template id="assets_backend" name="petstore" 
        inherit_id="web.assets_backend">
        <xpath expr="." position="inside">

     <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="/mypetstore/static/src/js/model_access.js">
     </script>

     <link href="/mypetstore/static/src/css/petstore.css" 
         rel="stylesheet">
     </link>
        </xpath>
    </template> 



    <record model="ir.ui.view" id="my_pet_store_form">
        <field name="name">my_pet_store_form</field>
        <field name="model">petstore.message</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <header>
         <button name="click_me" string="Click" 
              class="oe_highlight"/>
         </header>
            <form string="Message of the day">

                <group col="2">
                    <group>
                        <field name="data"/>
                    </group>
                </group>
            </form>
          </field>
       </record>
```

When user click on 'click_me' button, then it call a simple javascript function or action client. Just print an alert.
       JS part :
       odoo.define('mypetstore.model_access', function (require) {
        "use strict";
        var Class = require('web.Class');
        var Widget = require('web.Widget');
        var core = require('web.core');
        var utils = require('web.utils');

```
    jq('#click_me').bind('click', function(){
       alert("hello");
      });  
    });
```

Comment: It's "JavaScript", not "java script".

Answer (score 1):

First I would suggest you to give some ID attribute to Object, you want to use.
like

```
 <button name="click_me" id="click_me" string="Click" 
              class="oe_highlight"/>
```

JQuery:

```
jq('#click_me').bind('click', function(){
   alert("hello");
});
```

Comment: Getting error : "error: Some modules could not be started "

Comment: I added this code in my js file and getting the error. I have written my js code with the above code

Comment: use $ instead, I have rename JQuery object to jq. Sorry for inconvenience,
instead,

jq('#click_me')

use 

$('#click_me')

Comment: but.. its not working.. do we need to add those buttons inside template tag ?

Comment: getting this errorjQuery.fn.init {context: document, selector: "#click_me"}

Answer (score 0):

This is how your button should looks like, just add `onclick` whish is your handler.

```
         <header>
           <button onclick="myFunction()" name="click_me" string="Click" 
              class="oe_highlight"/>
         </header>
```

`myFunction()` will be your javascript code.

Now the alert code will be this:

```
<script type = "text/ javascript">  
  function myFunction() {
    alert("Hello! I am an alert box!!");
  }
</script>
```

hope it helps.